# Centos 7 takes 2Gb Ram after 3,4 idle hours

Tags: memory, performance, centos, memory-leaks

My Centos 7 Server takes from 160Mb to 2Gb Ram after 3,4 idle hours without any applications or services running, See htop response for more detail [Htop Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwPET.png)
. Whenever I start my apps (elasticsearch 1.4Gb and Spring Java app 300Mb) with early state 160Mb Ram. At first it shows 1.9Gb, after 1 day, it becomes 3.4/3.7, CPU 1 - 10%, very slow and unresponsive for almost actions. Some topics says that it's for caching file system, but maybe something is wrong here. Please give me some suggestions.

```
[ngocchien@localhost ~]$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3792        1968        1572          24         250        1609
Swap:             0           0
```

Comment: what does `top` / `htop` show?

Comment: Please see the link "Htop Response" in the question. My account has not yet permitted to attach an image.